# SAS: Proc Export and email error?

Tags: sql, email, sas, export

I have a code running on a daily basis. At the moment, it's creating an Excel-file (using proc export, see below) which it exports to a file path locally.

```
proc export data=work.data_set
outfile="FILE LOCATION AND NAME HERE" 
dbms=xlsx
replace;
sheet="Data sheet";
run;
```

Now I want to change this so that it will still make the excel file but instead of storing it locally, I want to have it send by email. How to do this? I tried to do it like this:

```
proc export data=work.data_set
  outfile= "FILE LOCATION AND NAME HERE"
  dbms=xlsx
  replace;
  sheet="Data sheet";
run;

        FILENAME demail EMAIL 
                        TO = ("xxx@xxx.com")
                        SUBJECT ="Data sheet"
                        FROM = "xxx@xxx.com" 
                        ATTACH = (  "FILE LOCATION AND NAME HERE");
        DATA _NULL_;
        FILE demail;
        nu = PUT(TODAY(),DDMMYYD10.);
        PUT 'Hello,';
        PUT;
        PUT 'Bye.'; 
        PUT;
        RUN;
```

But it gives me this error: 
"Excel found unreadable content in XXXX.xlsx. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbox? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."
Clicking Yes doesn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: When you get that error?  From the PROC EXPORT step or the DATA _NULL_ step that sends the email?

Comment: I don't get that error in SAS, I get it in Excel. So in SAS everything works and the file is being emailed. However, as soon as I try to open the file, it gives me this error.

Comment: If you open the excel file from the PROC export, does it open okay?  So it is the emailing that is trashing the file?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, it does open from SAS when the file is ready but after emailing it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your code: `ATTACH = (  "FILE LOCATION AND NAME HERE");`

Add these two lines to your code:

```
%let filepath= FILE LOCATION AND NAME HERE without quotes; 
put "!EM_ATTACH! &filepath";
```

Full Code:

```
%let filepath= FILE LOCATION AND NAME HERE without quotes; 
proc export data=work.data_set
  outfile= "FILE LOCATION AND NAME HERE"
  dbms=xlsx
  replace;
  sheet="Data sheet";
run;

        FILENAME demail EMAIL 
                        TO = ("xxx@xxx.com")
                        SUBJECT ="Data sheet"
                        FROM = "xxx@xxx.com" 
                        ;
        DATA _NULL_;
        FILE demail;
        nu = PUT(TODAY(),DDMMYYD10.);
        PUT 'Hello,';
        put "!EM_ATTACH! &filepath"; 
        PUT;
        PUT 'Bye.'; 
        PUT;
        RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have everything correct in your script, except for the `filename email`.

SAS does not know the `content_type` of your xlsx file, because as default it considers everything as a binary text file. Hence, messing up with your excel file's integrity. So, you'd have to explicitly mention your file's `content_type`. So, just a addition to your `filename email` statement -

```
FILENAME demail EMAIL 
TO = ("xxx@xxx.com")
SUBJECT ="Data sheet"
FROM = "xxx@xxx.com" 
ATTACH = ("%sysfunc(pathname(xllib))/my_excel_file.xlsx" ct="application/xlsx") /*check for the ct, abbr for content_type*/
ct = "text/html";
```

Then send an email with `data _null_;`

```
data _null_;
file demail;
put "Hello";
put "<br><br>"; /*two html style breaks, because it supports html tags for inserting a blank line. Simply put would not insert a line I guess*/
put "Bye!";
run;
```